# sudo without password on a newly created Linux server

Tags: linux, sudo

As part of automation, a new Linux server is created and I need to use sudo to install all dependencies.

```
echo "password" | sudo yum install <package>
```

The above command is still prompting for password which is causing an issue during automation.

Also tried following commands with no luck:

```
echo "password\n" | sudo yum install <package>
```

While the following command throws help options

```
$ echo "password" | sudo -S 
usage: sudo [-D level] -h | -K | -k | -V
```

Please suggest a solution to overcome the issue.

Comment: Your last option should work (that's what -S is for), but I think you mean `echo "password" | sudo -S yum install <package>`. Otherwise, you're not giving sudo anything to do.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how you do this depends on your distro, but you want to edit /etc/sudoers or add a file to /etc/sudoers,d which will allow your user (or group of you prefer) to run a command as sudo without a password.

Most distro will have fully commented files you can use as the basis for your change, otherwise Google "modifying sudoers" or similar.

Comment: `%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` lets anyone in the `wheel` group run sudo without a password, for example. `man sudoers` should be available on any system that supports /etc/sudoers